# how to get data out of voidptr with Python 3.6.3

Tags: python-3.x

Hello my Problem is to get my data out of an sip.voidptr.
Before I used Python 2.7 and this code:

```
 def winEvent(self, message):

        WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A

        if message.message == WM_COPYDATA:

            if sys.version.find("64 bit") != -1:
                structure = ctypes.string_at( message.lParam, 24 ) 
                data = struct.unpack("QQP", structure)

            unused, str_len, str_adr = data

            my_string = ctypes.string_at( str_adr, str_len )
```

Now I use Python 3 and had changed from "winevent" to "event_Type".
Does anybody have an idea or an example how to get the data out of the sip.voidptr?

The error massage i get is:

```
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 488, in string_at
return _string_at(ptr, size)
```

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000001

and before I get as my_string:

Name    ID

1   1_2

2   1_3

3   1_4

4   1_5

Comment: Hi! Could you please post the error you get and the result you'd like? That would help ;)

Comment: If you parse the 24 bytes as `QQQ` and print the three values, what do you get?  Also, please add code to check the size of `lParam` to make sure the data is the size you expect.

Comment: AttributeError: 'sip.voidptr' object has no attribute 'lParam'

Comment: when I take QQQ i get different values than QQP. Also the QQP values are different than the old one.